# iPhone 5 Launch image and App review

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I am about to submit a game app for a review.
Game is built with iOS SDK 6.1 and **iOS 5.1** as deployment target.

I currently do NOT have views for **iPhone 5** (wide) and 
the app is running in a **letterbox** mode on the IP5 which is fine.

The apple guidelines says that **Default-568@2x** (IP5 launch image) image is required, 
but I get a problem if I include this image - the app is not longer running in letterbox mode and looks broken (content is not centered, appears on the left in landscape).

If I do not include the launch image for the IP5, can I expect problem with app review?

Has anyone recently submitted app without IP5 launch image?

**IMPORTANT UPDATE:**

**Original question is now outdated! Since May 1st 2013 all submitted apps must have iPhone 5 launch image and you cannot rely on compatibility letterbox mode anymore.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not required  Default-568@2x if you want to run your app in letterbox....

Comment: OK, Thanks... Do you maybe have some official text(link) from Apple on this?

Comment: i am also live 1 app without Default-568@2x so you not worry about it

Comment: When you have submitted your app... how recent?

Comment: Great... that would mean that it is perfectly fine to omit image. Thanks again.

Comment: Wrong, as of May this year support for the iPhone 5 display (including a Default-568 image) is mandatory.

Comment: i give this ans in march when iphone 5 display support is not mandatory.

Answer (score 3):

You only include iPhone 5 launch image if you are supporting that screen. Not including the Default-568@2x.png launch image indicates that you are implicitly not supporting the screensize of the iPhone 5 and letterbox mode will be applied to iPhone 5 devices running your app.

You will not have any issues on the App Store. That is until Apple decides that all apps must support the 4" Retina screen going forward.

Answer (score 2):

I just got App rejected for not having the -568h launch screen, which it says has been required as of May 1.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I have updated my question with actual situation.

Answer (score 2):

You are no longer allowed to submit an app or an update to an existing app without support for the 4" retina display on iPhone 5 and iPod Touch 5. Your binary will be rejected by an automatic scan process before it enters the "Waiting For Review" state.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I have updated my question with actual situation.